# Vs2019 Node.jsのテンプレート作成でエラーで中止されてしまう。

Tags: visual-studio, node.js

**Node.jsのプロジェクトテンプレートが作成できない**
バグではないかと思うが色々試してみて、一番単純な、標準テンプレートからプロジェクトテンプレートが作成できない。
[image: プロジェクト-テンプレートのエクスポートを実行すると]

---

[image: STEP1]
Node.jsのプロジェクトをテンプレートから作成した所、画像の様なエラーが出て、
プロジェクトの作成が中止されました

[image: STEP2]

[image: STEP3 動作確認 出来上がったプロジェクトを何もいじらない!]

[image: STEP4 単純に何もいじらないでテンプレートを出力する]

[image: 2[プロジェクトのテンプレートの出力]

[image: 完了する]

[image: エラー画面]

Comment: 詳しく状況を説明して貰っていいですか？この作成を行う前どの様な事をしたか更新して欲しいです

Comment: タイトルの「Vs2019 Node.jsのテンプレート作成」と提示された画像は合っていますが、質問文章の「Node.jsのプロジェクトをテンプレートから作成した」とは違う逆方向の操作です。@su3158 さんコメントのように、実際には何を目的に、どのような手順で行ったのか更新してください。ちなみに「Node.jsのプロジェクトをテンプレートから作成した」後で、そのままプロジェクトから「テンプレートのエクスポート」を行うと、たしかに質問の画面になりました。何か必要な処理が不足しているのでは？ [プロジェクト テンプレートと項目テンプレート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Node.jsのテンプレートを作成するためにプロジェクトをテンプレート用に出力する。何を行っても上記のエラーがでる。

Comment: 私も同じエラーメッセージが出ました。 Visual Studio の右上に LiveShare の文字の右側をクリックすると、「問題の報告」というボタンがあります。 ここで Microsoft に直接「日本語で」報告してみてください。BING 翻訳で翻訳して対応してくれるます。・・ ただ、次のバージョンで解決するかは 不明です。 検索してみると 「https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/439411/export-template-wizard-template-export-failed.html」 Visual Studio 2017 の時から 同様の現象を報告して いまだに 問題が解決していないようです。

Comment: Node.jsのテンプレートが作成できなくて 何が困っていますか？